# How to get content of div in to a variable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In my HTML page div tag which id is div1 and button with id=btn1
when I click on Button then content of div should be appear alert box

how to print it on html page?

Comment: what you`ve tried.show your code

Comment: Content of the Div may contain the DOM elements as well. Then in that case you will get them in umformatted string

Answer (score 0):

You can use [contents](http://api.jquery.com/contents/) like this:

```
$('#btn1').on('click',function(){
   alert($('#div1').contents());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
<div id="div1">blah blah</div>
<input type="button" id="btn1" onClick="alertbox();">
<div id="new1"></div>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
function alertbox(){
 var newText=document.getElementById("div1").innerHTML;
 alert(newText);//alert
 document.getElementById("new1").innerHTML=newText;//prints in new div
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
add "good morning" in div tag and a button with id button.

your javascript code
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#button").click(function(){
 var data = $('div').text();
  alert (data);

  });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.yourButtonClass').click(function() {
     var contentsOfDiv = $('.yourDivClass').contents();
     alert(contentsOfDiv);
});
```